# There is no result after auto-deploy an app using GitLab CI/CD on Ubuntu

Tags: docker, ubuntu, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci-runner, autodeploy

In my laptop with `npm run serve` can load my Vue app on `http://localhost:8080` so i initialized git and push the app into a new Gitlab repository then created `Dockerfile` as below:

```
FROM node:12.18.3 AS build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM php:7.3-apache AS production-stage
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /var/www/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["apachectl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

I built an image `docker build -t vue-app .` and run it in my laptop by `docker run -d -p 80:80 --rm --name test-vue-app vue-app` that works well

So to use Gitlab CICD to deploy this app on my self-hosted Ubuntu as a home server created followed `.gitlab-ci.yml`

```
image: docker
services:
  - docker:dind
stages:
  - deploy
step-deploy-prod:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - docker build -t vue-app .
    - docker run -d -p 80:80 --rm --name testvueapp vue-app
```

also in another pc as server (with the fresh Ubuntu os), installed `ufw`, `open-ssh`, `apache2` and `php` and set my Router up to check this pc worked well as a simple home server which was positive

So connected to server device with ssh and install and register `gitlab-runner` and Docker as well.

Although with running Gitlab Pipeline can get **`Job succeeded`**, couldn't see any changes or update in server and load the result of running container even directly in server machine

> PS: by enabling apache2 on server device, i can load a simple php page on http://XX.XX.XX.XX (according to exist /var/www/html/index.php file) from any device but after running pipeline it doesn't work and if apache2 be enabled on server only can load php page instead Vue app